# Printing a 2D int vector from an object

Tags: c++, class, pointers

So I'm pretty sure it's having issues because it's trying to print the pointer instead of the value, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
class cName {
private:
    std::vector< std::vector<int>> *vect2d;
public:
    // initializes vector that contains x number of vectors
    // that each contain y number of ints
    cName(int x,int y); 
    void printVector(int);
}

void cName::printVector(int x) {
    for(int i=0; i<x; i++) {
        //have to get size because 
        // the number of ints in the vector will change
        for(int j=0; j< this->vect2d[i].size(); j++) 
            std::cout << this->vect2d[i][j]<<" ";
        std::cout<<"\n";
    }
}
```

I'm having issues printing a 2d vector I use in a class I'm making.  I get an error that says:

```
cannot bind 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>' 
lvalue to 'std::basic_ostream<char>&&'
```

### Question:

Could someone explain me why is throwing me that error and help me fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vect2d` member is a pointer to a vector of vectors of ints. You don't really need a pointer here, just use a vector of vectors of ints.

Your usage of this pointer does not produce any immediate errors because the subscript operator `array[index]` can be used on pointers. If you are not sure that your code is correct, prefer to use the range-checked `.at(index)` method for `std::vector` instances. Using an explicit method would have pointed you to your error, since there is no `.at(index)` method for pointers.

What the compiler currently sees when you call `this->vect2d[i].size()` is:

- `this->vect2d` of type `vector<vector<int>>*`, a complicated way of spelling `vect2d`. Note that this is a pointer type.
- `this->vect2d[i]` of type `vector<vector<int>>`, which is equivalent to `*(vect2d + i)`, but not to `(*vect2d)[i]` or `vect2d->at(i)`! Note that this is not a pointer type, but still two nested vectors.
- Therefore, the `.size()` is called on the vector that is `i` vector sizes away from your outer `*vect2d` container. Quite likely, this is invalid memory and could segfault.

When you later do `vect2d[i][j]`, that is actually equivalent to `*(vect2d + i)[j]` which should behave the same as `(vect2d + i)->at(j)`. But it is not `vect2d->at(i).at(j)`! Notably, it is of type `vector<int>` rather than `int`. That is the cause of your error message: there's no available `operator<<` to print vectors, so the compiler produces that quite incomprehensible error.